# How can I inject a build number with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'd like to inject a build number and version information to my project as it's built with webpack. For example, so that my code can do something like:

```
var buildInfo = require("build-info");
```

What would be the best way to generate that `build-info` module at build time?

Answer (score 81):

You can use the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) that will make your build info available inlined with your code:

**Config**

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   __VERSION__: JSON.stringify('12345')
})
```

**App code**

```
console.log(__VERSION__);
```

Comment: Where would you get the version # from though?  Do you have to read in the NPM package version from  `package.json`?

Comment: @beerdev: You would need to create your own number. I used the number of commits in the git repo: `var __versionString__ = childProcess.execSync('git rev-list HEAD --count').toString();`

Comment: I couldn't get childProcess to work in webpack, it seems like it's a server-side module only so it won't work in webpack, without a fix from the author? See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/744.  I added my solution below.

Comment: @MichaelBushe childProcess is available at build time, if you:

    ```var childProcess = require('child_process').```

@geon Nice example, it works well! I ran into a minor issue that was confusing at first. Maybe this was obvious & didn't seem worth mentioning, but I had to both trim and quote the git result to avoid syntax errors in my build (using webpack v. 1):

```new webpack.DefinePlugin({ __VERSION__: `"${__versionString__}"` })```

Comment: If you want to get the version number from `package.json`, you can do this: `__VERSION__: JSON.stringify(require("./package.json").version),`

Comment: Check this out for same solution but wider discussion https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/237#issuecomment-342129128

Comment: for github workflows you can use `process.env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER`

Answer (score 46):

I would do more **simpler**, just use `npm version patch` [(npm-version)](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) **(no plugin required)**

**package.json** (Example path version before building)

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm version patch && node build/build.js"
  }
}
```

So when you run `npm run build` this will patch the version (`1.0.0` to `1.0.1` in your package.json)

---

**Bonus:** You can also add this to your **config** (example `config/prod.env.js`)

```
'use strict'
const pkg = require('./package.json')
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  VERSION: pkg.version
}
```

Then you can use `process.env.VERSION` anywhere in your our JS

**Updated:** Or [just use](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars) `process.env.npm_package_version` without required to include package.json

Comment: Note that `npm version patch` affects GIT too;
"If run in a git repo, it will also create a version commit and tag. This behavior is controlled by git-tag-version, and can be disabled on the command line by running npm --no-git-tag-version version. It will fail if the working directory is not clean, unless the -f or --force flag is set."
source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version

Comment: `VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('../package.json').version)` will include the full package.json in the app. I'm not sure it's good thing.

Comment: running version patch makes an infinite loop

Answer (score 23):

There is a plugin to auto inject version from `package.json`.
It can inject it into HTML, CSS, JS as a comment, but also as a value by special tag [webpack-auto-inject-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-auto-inject-version).

**How to:**

First of all, you have to add it to your project:

```
npm i webpack-auto-inject-version
```

Then you need to set up your webpack config:

```js
var WebpackAutoInject = require('webpack-auto-inject-version');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new WebpackAutoInject()
    ]
}
```

As you want to inject it into javascript, you should add a tag inside your javascript file ( which will be changed to version during the webpack compilation )

```js
var version = '[AIV]{version}[/AIV]';
console.log(version);
```

**Auto increasing:**

You can set it up to auto increase the version directly from webpack by:

```
webpack --other-webpack-settings --major

webpack --other-webpack-settings -- minor

webpack --other-webpack-settings --patch
```

Where `--other-webpack-settings` is equal to your custom line args.
Simplifying - you need to att `--major`, `--minor` or `--patch` whenever you want to auto increase a version.

Comment: This plugin no longer works with Webpack 2.0 - custom arguments are no longer accepted.  You must prepend "env" to each one, which breaks the plugin's auto-increment capability.

Comment: Current version supports Webpack 2.

Comment: His questions was about a build number

Comment: Unmaintained package.  I was using this but am removing it now because it causes deprecation errors.

Comment: Using this with Webpack 4+ and it works like a charm. Dead simple to implement

Comment: no go for webpack 5 https://github.com/radswiat/webpack-auto-inject-version/pull/51

Answer (score 16):

Here is my recipe, derived from the other answers to this question. This makes use of the [WebpackVersionFilePlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-version-file-plugin) and [execa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa), and works great for me right now.

Install the plugins via npm:

```
npm install webpack-version-file-plugin --save-dev
npm install execa --save-dev
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const WebpackVersionFilePlugin = require('webpack-version-file-plugin');
const execa = require('execa');

const gitHash = execa.sync('git', ['rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD']).stdout;
const gitNumCommits = Number(execa.sync('git', ['rev-list', 'HEAD', '--count']).stdout);
const gitDirty = execa.sync('git', ['status', '-s', '-uall']).stdout.length > 0;

module.exports = {
// ... snip ...
plugins: [
    new WebpackVersionFilePlugin({
        packageFile: path.join(__dirname, 'package.json'),
        template: path.join(__dirname, 'version.ejs'),
        outputFile: path.join('build/ts/', 'version.json'),
        extras: {
            'githash': gitHash,
            'gitNumCommits': gitNumCommits,
            'timestamp': Date.now(),
            'dirty': gitDirty
        }
    }),
// ... snip ...
```

**version.ejs** (in project root):

```
{
    "name":       "<%= package.name %>",
    "buildDate":  <%= extras.timestamp %>,
    "version":    "<%= package.version %>",
    "numCommits": <%= extras.gitNumCommits %>,
    "hash":       "<%= extras.githash %>",
    "dirty":      <%= extras.dirty %>
}
```

So far, running this gets us a version.json file in `build/ts` with this content:

```
{
    "name":       "app name from package.json",
    "buildDate":  1518774257225,
    "version":    "2.0.1",
    "numCommits": 148,
    "hash":       "5a74b7a",
    "dirty":      false
}
```

The `dirty` flag indicates if the build included uncommitted or untracked changes.

I use TypeScript, so the following describes how to get the JSON file into my TypeScript code. If you don't have TypeScript, we have still reduced the problem to reading a JSON file. :-)

**app.ts:**

```js
import * as appVersionJson from './version.json';

export const appVersion: AppVersion = <any>appVersionJson;

export interface AppVersion {
    /** application name as specified in package.json */
    readonly name: string;

    /** build timestamp in milliseconds since the epoch */
    readonly buildDate: number;

    /** application version as specified in package.json */
    readonly version: string;

    /** number of commits in the Git repo */
    readonly numCommits: number;

    /** latest Git commit hash */
    readonly hash: string;

    /** flag is set when uncommitted or untracked changes are present in the workspace */
    readonly dirty: boolean;
}

// ...snip...
// now just use it in methods, for example:
appVersion.version + '.' + appVersion.numCommits + ' (' + appVersion.hash + ')'
```

Alright - hope this provides some more clues on how to have good build number information available in the code. Btw, [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) is a good way to bump the version numbers, when working like this.

Answer (score 4):

I have two files that I distribute that have the build number from the viewpoint of both git and npm (package.json).  I'd still like to pull this into my index.template.html in a meta tag, but haven't figured that out yet (how can I make a DEFINE from file contents or a cmd output?).

For git, I use webpack-shell-plugin to make a file with the git info:

```
const WebpackVersionFilePlugin = require('webpack-version-file-plugin');
plugins: [
new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildStart: [
        'git name-rev --name-only HEAD > dist/gitversion.txt',
        'git rev-list HEAD --count >> dist/gitversion.txt',
        'git rev-parse HEAD >> dist/gitversion.txt']
    }),
```

For npm, I add the npm version command ("npm version patch/minor/major") to (1) ensure there is no outstanding uncommitted changes in git - it fails if there are any and (2) update the package.json version and check it into git.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run lint && npm run init && npm version patch && webpack --config webpack.config.js",
```

I then distribute that using poorly documented, probably buggy, WebpackVersionFilePlugin.

```
const WebpackVersionFilePlugin = require('webpack-version-file-plugin');
new WebpackVersionFilePlugin({
      packageFile:path.join(__dirname, 'package.json'),
      outputFile: path.join('./dist/', 'version.json')
    }),
```

Using this template in the top directory:

```
{
  "version" : {
    "name":      "<% package.name %>",
    "buildDate": "<%= currentTime %>",
    "version":   "<%= package.version %>"
  }
}
```

Neither "package.name" nor "name" work.

The result is two files in my ./dist/directory.
gitversion.txt (branch, commit, count from head):

```
fmwk/feathers
9cfe791a09d3d748e8120e0628
51
```

and version.json:

```
{
  "version" : {
    "name":      "",
    "buildDate": "Fri Oct 21 2016 11:10:12 GMT+0800 (PHT)",
    "version":   "0.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Micheal Bushe, re "name" not working, do you have a name in your package.json?

Comment: I really can't understand is it answer or question? you said that not working or buggy, but not sure did you get it working?

Comment: The reason for name not working is due to a missing "=". You need to have "name":      "<%= package.name %>", in your template.

Answer (score 4):

If you can get away with **build version** rather than **code version** you can grab the build date during build time and use that for your version:

webpack.config.js

```js
const now = new Date()
const buildDate = `${now.getFullYear()}-${now.getMonth()+1}-${now.getDate()}`


module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({'BUILD_DATE': buildDate}),
  ]
  ...
}
```

Then anywhere in your code you'll be able to do

```js
console.log(process.env.BUILD_DATE)
```

This might suffice and doesn't require types definition, modifying your CI etc...

Comment: `now.getMonth()` start at `0` for January, so you may want to change that to `now.getMonth()+1`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding! I just learned this the hard way and forgot to update my answer!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work with TypeScript, so I helped myself by creating a file upon every compilation.

*webpack.config.js*

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const path = require('path'); 
fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src/version.ts')), 
`// This file is auto-generated by the build system. 
const BundleVersion = "${ new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10) }"; 
export default BundleVersion; 
`);
```

Then I just
`import BundleVersion from './version';`
and make sure it actually gets used somewhere (console.log or exposing it somewhere), so it is not being tree-shaken out, and that's it, timestamp (or version) in the bundle, created at compilation time (straight forward from here to read the package.json and use the package version if needed).

Answer (score 1):

I made a webpack loader that injects build information into an automatically generated file. You can find it [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-plugin-buildinfo).

Once you install it, you can use it like this:

```js
import buildinfo from "!webpack-plugin-buildinfo?gitHashShort&time!";
console.log(
    `MyCoolProject v${buildinfo.gitHashShort} compiled at ${new Date(
        buildinfo.time
    ).toISOString()}`
);
```

For more information, visit [the github repo](https://github.com/sportshead/webpack-buildinfo#readme).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the current date-time, here's the simplest way to accomplish this.

```js
const VERSION = "1";
const autoIncrementedVersion = `${VERSION}.${new Date().getTime()}`;

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            banner: `Author: Your Name
Date: ${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}
Project: Your Project Name
Version: ${autoIncrementedVersion}
License: (c) ${new Date().getFullYear()} Your Name
Description: Your project description
`
        }),
    ],
};
```

You'll see:

```js
/*!
 * Author: Your Name
 * Date: 5/3/2023
 * Project: Your Project Name
 * Version: 1.1683179722396
 * License: (c) 2023 Your Name
 * Description: Your project description
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with inserting the build information as a global variable directly in your `index.html` page, then the simplest approach may be to leverage the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` you're probably already using in your webpack config.

[This article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/inserting-variables-into-html-and-javascript-with-webpack-80f33625edc6) explains how to inject data into the `index.html` file at build time.  You can add arbitrary data to the plugin in your `webpack.config.js` file like this:

```js
plugins: [
    ...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "index.html",
        info: {
            foo: "bar",
            time: new Date().toLocaleString()
        },
    })
]
```

In the `index.html` template file, you can add an escape sequence to access that data and insert it (the `JSON.stringify()` outputs the data as an object literal that will be evaluated as part of the script):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.BUILD_INFO = <%= JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin.options.info, null, 2) %>;
</script>
```

You can then access that global variable from wherever you want in your code, like `console.log("Built at ", BUILD_INFO.time);`

For my use case, I just wanted to include a build timestamp as a comment in the HTML file.  So I added the timestamp to the plugin object and set `minify: false` to prevent comments from being stripped (and which also prevents the HTML from being output on a single line).

```js
plugins: [
    ...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        ...
        minify: false,
        buildTime: new Date().toLocaleString()
    })
]
```

This timestamp was then injected into an HTML comment like this:

```html
<!-- Built at <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.buildTime %> -->
```