# Versioning in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gulp, auth0-lock

I have multiple javascript files that are bundled and minified in one file "bundle-min.js" and is linked in one of my html page. Now I want to introduce versioning in those js files. Means when I change any of my js file, I want my bundle file version to be updated. I have found gulp-version-append but I am not sure whether it will help me or not. Also I don't want to update the reference link of bundle-min.js in my html file again and again. I want my html page to get the latest version it self somehow. Is this possible and what's the best approach? Any help?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of modules available for this. it depends on your module loader.

**Webpack**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-version-file-plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/versioning-webpack-plugin

or you can use define plugin for this

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

**Refer**
[How can I inject a build number with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663175/how-can-i-inject-a-build-number-with-webpack)

Comment: Is this possible using gulp?

Comment: I haven't tried in gulp. Please check this plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-version-append

This might help you